# VB.net get text from a td that has same ID/class as other td

Tags: vb.net, classname

From a webbrowser, I would like to get the text from a TD that has same classname than other td.

Here is the html code :

```
<table>
<tr class = "1" data-gtmid = "1111">
<td class = "ex"> data1 </td>
<td class = "tg"> data2 </td>
<td class = "sh"> data3 </td>
<tr class = "1" data-gtmid = "2222">
<td class = "ex"> data4 </td>
<td class = "tg"> data5 </td>
<td class = "sh"> data6 </td>
<tr class = "1" data-gtmid = "3333">
<td class = "ex"> data7 </td>
<td class = "tg"> data8 </td>
<td class = "sh"> data9 </td>
</table>
```

The problem for me is that there are classname in common.
For example, data1, data4 and data7 have the classname "ex".
I think I should specify in which row the td is with the "data-gtmid" (because all tr have the same classname too "1"), but I don't know how to do this...

Any idea to extract data 5 for example plz?
TY

Comment: Are you already using some kind of library to parse the HTML? You might want to consider [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) or [HTMLAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/). Or, if this is XHTML, you could use LINQ.

Comment: You can use the `WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName()` method (the Tag name can be `"TD"`, here). Then filter the elements by attribute (`GetAttribute()`) where the `className` is `"tg"`, for example. Then, how did you determine that the element which contains `data5` is the one you want? Because it's in the second row? Then get the element at index 1. Or does it contain some specific text? Then select the HtmlElement where the `InnerText.Contains()` the string you're looking for. To perform a selection, you need to apply the same logic you applied using *your eyes*.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys. I ll try these solutions